# jQuery: how to select the text in a text input

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a button linked to a text field that will let me select all the text in a textarea so the user can copy it to the clipboard.  I've tried this:

```
$('#selectCode').click(function() {
     var input = $('#MyTextBox');
     input.focus();
     input.select();
});
```

based on several examples I found online where you focus on the input and then select it.  But this doesn't seem to work in jQuery -- at least the way I'm doing it.  Can someone help?

Comment: This code works: http://jsbin.com/imekez. Perhaps something else on your page is interfereing?

Comment: I usually use pure javascript for this. Pretty much the same thing just replacing the `$("#MyTextBox");` to `document.getElementById('MyTextBox');`

Comment: These must be something else on the page interfering.  I tried the code below and it doesn't work either.  Ok, thanks, guys.

Comment: possibly include the html snippets around the textbox and button?  Might help.

Comment: There was a typo in the id of the input.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $("#selectCode").click(function(){
     $("#MyTextBox").select();       

   });
});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vqGM4/3/